# How to change a variable in a tuple of tuples to a tuple with wanted value

Tags: python, tuples

How to add a variable to each tuple's item that is all ready in a tuple and make the item and the variable a tuple.
Input:
`x = (('U', 'H', 'S', 'H'), ('H', 'U', 'H', 'S'), ('U', 'H', 'H', 'U'))`

Wanted output:
`y = ((('U',0), ('H',0), ('S',0), ('H',0)), (('H',0), ('U',0), ('H',0), ('S',0)), (('U',0), ('H',0), ('H',0), ('U',0)))`

I tried to convert it into a dictionary and then back to a tuple but it seemed inefficient. Is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: Can you share the solution you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use generator:

```
y = tuple(tuple((sub_el, 0) for sub_el in el) for el in x)
```

Comment: clean and elegant, Thanks!